# Data Stream as Disjoint intervals

Tags: java, interval

I was asked the following question:

> Given a data stream input of non-negative integers a1, a2, ..., an,
>   ..., summarize the numbers seen so far as a list of disjoint
>   intervals.
>
> For example, suppose the integers from the data stream are 1, 3, 7, 2,
>   6, ..., then the summary will be:

```
[1, 1] 
[1, 1], [3, 3] 
[1, 1], [3, 3], [7, 7] 
[1, 3], [7, 7] 
[1, 3], [6, 7]
```

My approach to this problem was to keep adding the numbers to a structure such as a TreeSet which will help with the in-order iteration. While iterating I can check whether the values are consecutive and if they are, I add them to the existing interval, otherwise I create a new interval. Here's the code I have to accomplish it:

```
public class SummaryRanges {
    private TreeSet<Integer> streamNums;
    /** Initialize your data structure here. */
    public SummaryRanges() {
        streamNums= new TreeSet<Integer>();
    }

    public void addNum(int val) {
        if(!streamNums.contains(val)) {
            streamNums.add(val);    
        }
    }

    public List<Interval> getIntervals() {
        ArrayList<Interval> buffer = new ArrayList<Interval>();
        if(!streamNums.isEmpty()) {
            int start = streamNums.first();
            int end = start;
            Iterator<Integer> streamIter = streamNums.iterator();
            if(streamIter.hasNext()) streamIter.next();
            while(streamIter.hasNext()) {
                int i = streamIter.next();
                if(i == end + 1) {
                    end = i;    
                } else {
                    buffer.add(new Interval(start,end));
                    start = i;
                    end = i;
                }
            }
          buffer.add(new Interval(start,end));  
        }   
        return buffer;
    }
}
```

It will be great to get some pointers on how to do this better.

Comment: Are you on Java 8?

Comment: yes, I am on java 8.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Using a `TreeSet` effectively

Since you are already using a `TreeSet` as the underlying data structure, you need not check if it contains the incoming number `val` or not in `addNum(int)` as any `Set` implementation will not store duplicate values. Also, to skip the first element in the `TreeSet`, you can do:

```
int start = streamNums.first();
Iterator<Integer> streamIter = streamNums.tailSet(start, false).iterator();
```

This avoids having to `next()` on the `Iterator` manually.

#### Inverting `if`s

```
public List<Interval> getIntervals() {
    ArrayList<Interval> buffer = new ArrayList<Interval>();
    if(!streamNums.isEmpty()) {
        // ...
    }
    return buffer;
}
```

You can reduce one level of nesting if you simply returned a `new ArrayList` first:

```
public List<Interval> getIntervals() {
    if(streamNums.isEmpty()) {
        return new ArrayList<>();
    }
    List<Interval> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
    // ...
    return buffer;
}
```

#### Interfaces over implementations and type inference

As illustrated above, `buffer` can be declared as a `List` instead of `ArrayList`, and at least you are not making the same mistake in the method return type declaration. Also, since Java 7, you can rely on [type inference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/language/type-inference-generic-instance-creation.html) to eliminate mentioning the generic type a second time, by using the 'diamond operator' `<>`.

#### Java 8 stream-based processing

Since you are on Java 8, you can look towards its stream-based processing capabilities as the *appropriate* way of solving your problem. It's relatively simple to adapt your solution to [*reduce* an integer stream to a `List<Interval>`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/streams/reduction.html), or more specifically to create a [`Collector`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.html) out of your solution:

```
public class TreeInterval implements Collector<Integer, TreeInterval, List<Interval>> {

    private final TreeSet<Integer> cache = new TreeSet<>();

    @Override
    public BiConsumer<TreeInterval, Integer> accumulator() {
        return (ti, integer) -> ti.cache.add(integer);
    }

    @Override
    public Set<Characteristics> characteristics() {
        return Collections.singleton(Characteristics.UNORDERED);
    }

    @Override
    public BinaryOperator<TreeInterval> combiner() {
        return (a, b) -> { a.cache.addAll(b.cache); return a; };
    }

    private List<Interval> toResult() {
        if (cache.isEmpty()) {
            return new ArrayList<>();
        }
        List<Interval> buffer = new ArrayList<>();
        int start = cache.first();
        int end = start;
        Iterator<Integer> iterator = cache.tailSet(start, false).iterator();
        while (iterator.hasNext()) {
            int i = iterator.next();
            if (i == end + 1) {
                end = i;
            } else {
                buffer.add(new Interval(start, end));
                start = i;
                end = i;
            }
        }
        buffer.add(new Interval(start, end));
        return buffer;
    }

    @Override
    public Function<TreeInterval, List<Interval>> finisher() {
        return TreeInterval::toResult;
    }

    @Override
    public Supplier<TreeInterval> supplier() {
        return TreeInterval::new;
    }
}
```

In summary, a `Collector` needs to know how to:

- supply an accumulator: represented by the `supplier()` method.
- accumulate an `Integer`: represented by the `accumulator()` method.
- combine the accumulators into one: represented by the `combiner()` method.
- extract the results of the last accumulator to the required type: represented by the `finisher()` method. In turn, your solution is used as a [method reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/methodreferences.html) within this.
- provide a set of [characteristics](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Collector.Characteristics.html) that describes itself, for potential optimization: represented by the `characteristics()` method.

For illustration, this is how it can be used:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    IntStream.of(1, 3, 7, 2, 6)
        .boxed()
        .collect(new TreeInterval())
        .forEach(System.out::println);
}

// Output
[1,3]
[6,7]
```

1. Construct an [`IntStream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html) with the values `1, 3, 7, 2, 6`.
2. [Box](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/IntStream.html#boxed--) it into a `Stream<Integer>`.
3. Collect the values using an instance of `TreeInterval`.
4. For each `Interval`, print it using `System.out.println(Object)`.